# What are Columbus' 32 rules for survival in Zombieland?

Tags: zombieland

```
1. Cardio  
...
32. Enjoy the little things.
```

Please help me feel in the blanks.

Comment: #2 Double Tap! (Or Ziploc bags?) Anyway, a canon answer won't fill in all the blanks.

Comment: I'll try to sit down and find a definitive list, but so far I've found at least three differing versions of the supposed full list.

Comment: I've found a video from Sony mentioning rule #33 ("Swiss Army").

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This site ([www.ZombieLandRules.com](http://www.zombielandrules.com/all-zombieland-rules/)) seems to contain a pretty solid list of rules that were mentioned in the film, additional materials (such as deleted scenes and the mobile app game) as well as those mentioned by cast and crew in various interviews.

> **Zombieland Rules from the movie & promotional material**
>
> ## 1 – Cardio
>
> ## 2 – The Double Tap
>
> ## 3 – Beware of Bathrooms
>
> ## 4 – Seatbelts
>
> ## 5 – ???
>
> ## 6 – The Skillet*
>
> ## 7 – Travel Light
>
> ## 8 – Get A Kickass Partner*
>
> ## 9 – ???
>
> ## 10 – ???
>
> ## 11 – ???
>
> ## 12 – Bounty Paper Towels*
>
> ## 13 – ???
>
> ## 14 – ???
>
> ## 15 – Bowling Ball*
>
> ## 16 – ???
>
> ## 17 – Don’t Be A Hero
>
> ## 18 – Limber Up
>
> ## 19 – ???
>
> ## 20 – ???
>
> ## 21 – Avoid Strip Clubs*
>
> ## 22 – When In Doubt, Know Your Way Out
>
> ## 23 – ???
>
> ## 24 – ???
>
> ## 25 – ???
>
> ## 26 – ???
>
> ## 27 – ???
>
> ## 28 – ???
>
> ## 29 – The Buddy System*
>
> ## 30 – ???
>
> ## 31 – Check The Back Seat
>
> ## 32 – Enjoy The Little Things
>
> ## 33 – Swiss Army Knife*
>
> *Rules marked with an asterisk are from promotional material and should not yet be considered canon.
>
> **Zombieland Deleted Scenes Rules**
>
> ## 2 – The Ziploc Bag
>
> ---
>
> **Zombieland Rules from interviews with cast and crew**
>
> **4 new rules have been mentioned by the writers Paul Wernick and Rhett Reese but they don’t have numbers associated with them.**
>
> ## ??? – Always carry a change of underwear
>
> ## ??? – Double-knot your shoe[lace]s
>
> ## ??? – It’s a marathon, not a sprint. Unless it is a sprint, then sprint
>
> ## ??? – Pack your stain stick
>
> ---
>
> **Zombieland Rules from the cellphone game**
>
> ## 2 – Zipplock
>
> ## 3 – Double Tap
>
> ## 5 – Shoot First
>
> ## 7 – Incoming!
>
> ## 8 – Break it up
>
> ## 9 – With your bare hands
>
> ## 10 – Don’t swing low
>
> ## 11 – Use your feet
>
> ## 13 – Shake it off
>
> ## 22 – Opportunity knocks
>
> ## 24 – Use your thumbs